How to draw a quantum measurement in TikZ LaTeX
I want to draw a quantum measurement in TikZ LaTeX as the following image! Any ideas?


Have you checked quantikz? It has something like that in the examples on page 5. https://ctan.org/pkg/quantikz?lang=en (circuitikz is not really oriented to quantum circuits)

Thanks, but their measurement is different! @Rmano

So please post what you tried and where you got stuck, and somebody will help. Otherwise, this question seems a "please do it for me" type, which are quite frowned upon here. Thanks and welcome!

This package also does not work on overleaf! @Rmano

I did not try honestly! I am fairly new to TikZ! @Rmano

Does this answer your question? Measurement meter quantum circuit with TikZ

It is similar but not the exact same figure! @Sebastiano

@NickCooper Excuse me but do you are able to personalize the arc and the line in the link added?

You can use a \pic and redraw the shown image using simple TikZ commands, then use it in a similar way as a node. But on this site you should come up with some own code first. It should not be too difficult to draw this using TikZ.

Here an adapted code from Measurement meter quantum circuit with TikZ of @Jasper Habicht.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{meter/.append style={draw, inner sep=10, rectangle, font=\vphantom{A}, minimum width=30, line width=.8,  path picture={\draw[black] ([shift={(.1,.3)}]path picture bounding box.south west) to[bend left=50] ([shift={(-.1,.3)}]path picture bounding box.south east);\draw[black,-{Latex[length=8mm, width=1.8mm]}] ([shift={(0,.2)}]path picture bounding box.south) -- ([shift={(.4,-.1)}]path picture bounding box.north);}}}
\begin{circuitikz}
\node[meter] (meter) at (0,0) {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}



This is great, thanks!
